# what android permission causes "device & app history"

Tags: permissions, manifest, device

I am trying to install an app from Google Play store and I see Device & app history permission.

does anyone know what android permission in manifest causes "Device & app history" permission?

Device & app history
Allows the app to view one or more of: information about activity on the device, which apps are running, browsing history and bookmarks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

OK, after researching about this mysteries Android permissions, I got my answer from Adam P. in Android Communities. Thanks Adam.

1. If you look at the picture below, you will see a description for Device & app history permission for an Android app. At first, this permission description sounds really bad. If you don't know the reasoning behind why all those 3 permissions listed under one group, you would think that this app is really accessing your list of apps, your browsing history and bookmarks. WOW! what a scary thing!

   We all know that Google's Android permission system is really broken. From the non tech-savvy people's point of view, this message will scare them and they may not even install your app. Simply, this message on the permission dialog is misleading. Why? actually this sample app needs "retrieve running apps" permission only.

   Now, if you pay attention to the message, it reads "one or more of:". What do you mean by "one or more of:"?

   Why can't you just display it in a simple format instead of confusing users?

   Lesson learned: apparently, one permission from that group is enough to trigger to show that message shown in #1.

   Here are the permissions under Device & app history group permission:

   - Read sensitive log data (android.permission.READ_LOGS)
   - Retrieve system internal state (android.permission.DUMP)
   - Read your web bookmarks and history (com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS)
   - Retrieve running apps (android.permission.GET_TASKS)

   [image]
2. Now, if you close the dialog shown on #1 screenshot and then scroll down on the Google Play Store app, you will see a text link reads "View details" shown on #2 screenshot. Click that to see a little bit different version of these permissions. By the way, this link is hidden down in the page and I wonder how many users find that link.

   [image]
3. This is what I like. It's clear and concise. Whereas in #1 screenshot, you need to be a linguistic teacher to understand what Google's copyeditors' message mean. Obviously, the first permission dialog in #1 confused me.

   [image]
4. OK, this is an extra bonus for you to get confused even more. This sample app apparently requires your phone number to create an account. Nowadays, a lot of social apps started doing that.

   Now, if you hold down your app's launcher icon and drag onto App Info button, you will go to your app's details section. Suddenly, you will see this yellow scary message reads "this may cost you money". Well, I know this app does not make a call at all. It just used your phone number to register an account. Google, is it fair to scare people off with that message when the app doesn't really do that?

#### Conclusion:

Lesson learned; the group permission can be triggered by one permission within and that can cause to show those scary messages.

I am still waiting for the day that Google changes these permissions system. Instead of asking me Yes or No question before installing, I would like to customize the app permissions while I am installing.

Wouldn't it be nice if you check/uncheck each permission and install the app? And, you can turn on more permissions in the app's settings view if necessary. By the way, App Ops won't help with that much.

[image]

some more info at: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en

Comment: Great answer! In this case, I think the groups are reasonable. The app list is just as sensitive as browsing history (e.g. facebook app vs browsing facebook.com). IMHO, too many apps request permissions that are not required. Most social apps do not need my phone number to perform their function (also, I get charged if they leak the number while I am outside my city).

Answer (score 22):

You're leaving out an essential point concerning these permissions groups. According to Google's [Review app permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en) (your source) it states the following:

> Permissions groups
>
> Permissions groups are designed to show what an app will be able to
>   access on your device. With permissions groups, you can quickly see
>   what capabilities or information an app may use before downloading it.
>   Also, you can review individual permissions at any time using the
>   Google Play Store Play Store app.
>
> It's a good idea to review permissions groups before downloading an
>   app. Once you've allowed an app to access a permissions group, the app
>   may use any of the individual permissions that are part of that group.
>   You won't need to manually approve individual permissions updates that
>   belong to a permissions group you've already accepted.

I got an app on my phone that I wanted to update today and noticed that it now asks for access to the Device & app history permission group. As you suggested, the drill down via the Permissions details shows that in reality, it is only requiring the 'retrieve running apps' permission. Great! .. you might think ... but NOT!

If I proceed and accept this now in good faith that I'm OK for this app to see what apps I got running, a subsequent update of this app is NOT going to ask again for access to the Device & app history permission group if they ADD another permission from this same permission group. In other words, today I approve this, granting access to Retrieve running apps (android.permission.GET_TASKS), but as a consequence of that **I will not** get a new approval request if a next app update adds any of these permissions:

- Read sensitive log data (android.permission.READ_LOGS)
- Retrieve system internal state (android.permission.DUMP)
- Read your web bookmarks and history (com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS)

My conclusion is that if the developers of this app decides they want to obtain eg. my browser history for whatever reason (ads?), they can just add the com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS to their app and I will not be notified when it automatically updates since I have already granted the Device & app history permission group.

Answer (score 1):

Device & app history
Allows the app to view one or more of: information about activity on the device, which apps are running, browsing history and bookmarks